# How to convert Native Query to JPA Query

Tags: sql, jpa, subquery

Suppose that i have 3 tables

```
STUDENT
----------------------
STUDENT_ID | FULL_NAME
======================

SUBJECT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
SUBJECT_ID | SUBJECT_NAME | STATUS | START_DATE | END_DATE | STUDENT_ID
=======================================================================

CLAZZ
-------------------------------------------
CLAZZ_ID | CLAZZ_NAME | STATUS | STUDENT_ID
===========================================
```

I want to get the number of subjects and classes that the student learn in a period of time. So i can use this native SQL:

```
WITH SUBJECT_COUNT AS (
    SELECT STUDENT_ID, COUNT(*) AS SUB_COUNT
    FROM SUBJECT
    WHERE STATUS=1 AND DateParam >= START_DATE AND DateParam <= END_DATE
    GROUP BY STUDENT_ID
), CLAZZ_COUNT AS (
    SELECT STUDENT_ID, COUNT(*) AS CLZ_COUNT
    FROM CLAZZ
    WHERE STATUS=1
    GROUP BY STUDENT_ID
)
SELECT S.STUDENT_ID, S.FULL_NAME, SC.SUB_COUNT, CC.CLZ_COUNT
FROM STUDENT S 
    LEFT JOIN SUBJECT_COUNT SC ON S.STUDENT_ID=SC.STUDENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN CLAZZ_COUNT CC ON S.STUDENT_ID=CC.STUDENT_ID
ORDER BY SC.SUB_COUNT, CC.CLZ_COUNT
```

How can I convert this native SQL to JPA 2.1 SQL. Or any others solutions that i can get the same result would be good. 
Thank you very much

Comment: Why you can't use `NativeQuery`?

Comment: My project use almost JPA query. And it uses one technique to map data and POJO object. I dont want to use another way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EntityManager.createNativeQuery` it is normal if you don't have specific reasons why you should use it `HQL`. Most simple way use native query it is:

```
    em.createNativeQuery("WITH SUBJECT_COUNT AS ( " +
            "    SELECT STUDENT_ID, COUNT(*) AS SUB_COUNT " +
            "    FROM SUBJECT " +
            "    WHERE STATUS=1 AND DateParam >= :START_DATE AND DateParam <= :END_DATE " +
            "    GROUP BY STUDENT_ID " +
            "), CLAZZ_COUNT AS ( " +
            "    SELECT STUDENT_ID, COUNT(*) AS CLZ_COUNT " +
            "    FROM CLAZZ " +
            "    WHERE STATUS=1 " +
            "    GROUP BY STUDENT_ID " +
            ")\n" +
            "SELECT S.STUDENT_ID, S.FULL_NAME, SC.SUB_COUNT, CC.CLZ_COUNT " +
            "FROM STUDENT S  " +
            "    LEFT JOIN SUBJECT_COUNT SC ON S.STUDENT_ID=SC.STUDENT_ID " +
            "    LEFT JOIN CLAZZ_COUNT CC ON S.STUDENT_ID=CC.STUDENT_ID " +
            "ORDER BY SC.SUB_COUNT, CC.CLZ_COUNT").setParameter("START_DATE", startDate).setParameter("END_DATE", endDate).getSingleResult();
```

You can put query to the `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation on your entity then for creation query you need use `EntityManager.createNamedQuery` instead `EntityManager.createNativeQuery`. This will see an error in the query at compile.

Native query result you can wrap to the POJO object [look more info](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/)